# Зачем нужен файл *.ru в папке с шаблоном Joomla?

Tags: локализация, joomla

Скачал тему OT Alatinum для Joomla, установил, рабираюсь
В архиве с шаблоном нашел файл forjoomla.ru, размер файла 1.13 Мб. Если это файл локализации шаблона, то как его использовать?
P.S. Кто знает Joomla и может поотвечать на вопросы новичка -  напишите пожалуйста в скайп **nightfall876**. Буду весьма признателен)

Answer (score 1):

Таких файлов в шаблоне Joomla вообще не должно быть. Скорей это как реклама сайта, с которого был скачан шаблон, так что можно смело его удалять. А локализации в шаблоне как бы нет. Локализация идет только на движок (CMS Joomla).